cython 0.29.24 & 0.29.25 crashed in Windows 11 and python 3.11.9 with fatal error "'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory."
In Windows 11 and Python 3.11.9, I ran cython 0.29.24 and 0.29.25 for a pyx file and got this fatal error: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory.
I did not see this problem when like 3 years ago with python 3.7.
The issue seemingly has been raised in many posts in the last two years. One solution is the page (https://groups.google.com/g/s3ql/c/Ldrll7KdXQE) and says we can solve this by running
setup.py build_cython

I have no idea about the contents of their setup.  I have no rights to post in their website.  So I used mine as follows.
# setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    name="CnQ",
    version='1.0.1',
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        [
            Extension("src.qqq", ["src/qqq.pyx"]),
        ],
        build_dir="build_cythonize",
        compiler_directives={
            'language_level' : "3",
            'always_allow_keywords': True,
        }
    ),
    cmdclass=dict(
        build_ext=build_ext
    ),
)

But when I typed in 'python setup.py build_cython', my python did not recognize build_cython.
Then here is another post （https://github.com/SpotlightKid/python-rtmidi/issues/115%EF%BC%89 suggesting pip install python-rtmidi. But when I typed in
pip install git+https://github.com/SpotlightKid/pythonrtmidi.git@eb16ab3268b29b94cd2baa6bfc777f5cf5f908ba#egg=python-rtmidi
my pip crashed.
Then there are people suggesting copying longintrepr.h to some folder.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979674/gensim-install-in-python-3-11-fails-because-of-missing-longintrepr-h-file
(check the reply by user @Srikant)

According to this, I copied it to
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
But cython still yielded the same fatal error. Can someone help? You suggestions and solutions will be greatly appreciated.
I googled tens of pages and tried several suggestions and still could not get cython working as two years ago.

You either need to upgrade Cython to a higher version (i.e. 0.29.39 is the most recent version in the branch you're trying to use) or use Python 3.10 or less.

This is because the file was moved in Python 3.11. Therefore Cython had to adapt. Their you either need a higher version of Cython or a lower version of Python

Thanks, David!  I will try your suggestions later.  For now I temporarily solve the problem according to the trick by Srikant.

Thanks to all!
I kind of solve the problem with the dirty trick according to a comment by Srikant in the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74979674/gensim-install-in-python-3-11-fails-because-of-missing-longintrepr-h-file
(check the reply by user @Srikant)

But I need to find the location of my python.exe in my conda environment.
Then I copied longintrepr.h to the include folder in the environment folder.
That is
~/anaconda3/envs/my311/include

DavidW also suggested to either upgrade my Cython or downgrade my python.
Thanks!
I will try that later.
